# Unable to get the grub even after Boot-Repair is performed

Tags: boot, grub2, dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair

I have hp pavillion sleekbook 14 with windows 8. I installed ubuntu only to find out that it cant be booted. I performed boot-repair as others in this forum have did. The boot-repair was successful.  But in the end it showed me a message,"Please do not forget to make your BIOS boot on sda2/EFI/ubuntu/shimx64.efi file!" and my url is http://paste.ubuntu.com/5660106/
I dont know what that means . I think i ll be able to get the grub when i perform the above action. Can anyone help me to boot bios on that shimx64.efi file pls!!

Comment: The question claimed as an answer concerns a WUBI install, and there's no evidence of a WUBI install in this case. Although there have been similar questions asked here that might be suitable referents, IMHO the suggested one is *not* one of them! IMHO, this type of problem is better solved in a forum than on this site, since it's likely to involve a system-specific firmware bug.

Answer (score 0):

You must create an efi boot partition during install. I make one about 100MB in size and it is fine. During install create a partition and assign efi filesystem.